# Oops, I broke my MBR, what do I do?

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I installed Mavericks a couple weeks ago and discovered to my dismay that last night, I couldn't boot into my windows install via bootcamp. I'd encountered this problem before, and without entirely understanding it, I fixed it using gdisk, and the directions
[located here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4144252).

So naturally (and foolishly) I looked up that page and followed the directions, and bam. I can't get into either Mac or Windows.

Presumably then there's a problem with my guid partition table or my MBR, or both. I'm using the apple internet recovery tool and the terminal won't let me run the version of gdisk I had previously downloaded. It gives me "Illegal instruction 4" when I try.

I have maybe 4 partitions: 1. mac osx, 2. mac recovery, 3. a 15 gb partition for storage, and 30 gb windows partition.

I've posted the results of gpt show and diskutil list. Past that, I'm a little lost. I've got a windows box I can install ubuntu or some other recovery tool on, but people were saying ubuntu will write to disk and ruin things. Suggestions?

```
-bash-3.2# gpt show disk0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  146496248      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  146905888    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  148175424       1472         
  148176896   29284352      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  177461248   59514880      5  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  236976128       2015         
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            75.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data MACINTOSH H             15.0 GB    disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                30.5 GB    disk0s5
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.2 GB     disk1
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Mac OS X Base System    1.2 GB     disk1s2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk2
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk3
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk4
/dev/disk5
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk7
/dev/disk8
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *2.1 MB     disk8
/dev/disk9
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk9
/dev/disk10
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk10
/dev/disk11
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk11
/dev/disk12
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk12
```

Comment: Did you try simple things like Safe booth, or single user mode or recovery mode "cmd-r"

Comment: don't have an immediate answer for you on this; however, officially with bootcamp, you should not have 4 partitions only the OSX, Recovery and Bootcamp, anything else will indeed cause issues.